# How to create a 3 section's in a row inside the colophon footer (wordpress)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, footer

I am trying to edit my `footer.php` in my child-theme (localhost for now, no link to share) in a way that I won't loose the "powered by ..." text. The theme authors (and wordpress too) surely deserve to be referenced there with the great work they do.

I want to add a row with 3 sections, in-line, and above the "footer-menu" and "site-generator" that came with the template. Can you point where the html structure, or the css, is/are incorrect?
Here's what I added to my child-theme `footer.php` and `style.css`:

```
<footer id="colophon" role="contentinfo">
    <div class="footer-wrap">

<!-- New inserted code STARTS HERE -->

<div class="engage-row">
    <div class="col-1">
        <img src="http://localhost/apoise/wp-content/themes/virality-child/images/footer/campaigntest.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <img src="http://localhost/apoise/wp-content/themes/virality-child/images/footer/about-engage.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <!-- Will add a subscription form here -->
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- Newly inserted code ENDED HERE -->

<div class="footer-wfix">

<?php virality_footer_nav(); ?>

<div id="site-generator">
    <?php echo __('&copy; ', 'virality') . esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) );  ?>
   <?php if ( is_front_page() && ! is_paged() ) : ?>
   <?php _e('- Powered by ', 'virality'); ?><a href="<?php echo esc_url( __( 'http://wordpress.org/', 'virality' ) ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Semantic Personal Publishing Platform', 'virality' ); ?>"><?php `enter code here`_e('WordPress' ,'virality'); ?></a>
   <?php _e(' and ', 'virality'); ?><a href="<?php echo esc_url( __( 'http://wpdevshed.com/', 'virality' ) ); ?>"><?php _e('WP Dev Shed', 'virality'); ?></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>

</div>
```

In `style.css` I added:

```
.col-1{
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
.col-2{
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
.col-3{
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
```

How can I keep the footer_nav and the site-generator in a new line under the new row I created? Right now they are extending to the right. Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your css file you need to add

```
div.footer-wfix {
   clear:left;
}
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: I had added, after some research,
`.footer-wfix {

Comment: Cool. One more thing:
If the footer-wrap, engage-row, footer-wfix and site-generator divs are all INSIDE the <footer>, and this one has the full width and grey background in the CSS, how come these divs move BELOW the grey background, instead of the lower edge of this grey background <footer> become extended as the divs move down? Can the footer size (or grey background) be made responsive to the editing/extention of its containing divs?

glad for your help here

Comment: To be honest, it's very difficult to answer you with just bit and pieces. "Normally" the footer should extend, but it's possible there is something in the existing css that limits its height , like max-height or simple height

Comment: It was the height property, indeed. I added the value "auto" to it and it worked. Thanks!